# How to see or debug chrome content script in firefox nightly (webextensions)

Tags: firefox-addon, content-script, firefox-addon-webextensions

Trying to port a working chrome extension to Firefox Nightly 46.0a1 and have a simple question! How do I get the content script to execute or see it at all?

Everything else but the content script seam to be running OK as the background script execute and the popup box is visible. I am able to debug these part of the code.

But the content script do not seam to run in any way!

As far as I understand it is supposed to be part of the normal page javascript environment and visible in the debugger - but it is not. Unable to see any error messages anywhere etc.

Might have used some unsupported API by mistake, but still strange that I get no warnings and are unable to see anything.

Any proposal about how to proceed?

Manifest file below:

```
{
  "name": "Bla Bla",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "A description",
  "homepage_url": "https://aaa.org",
  "icons": 
  {
    "16": "icons/lock_red16.png",
    "48": "icons/lock_red48.png",
    "128": "icons/lock_red128.png"
  },
  "default_locale": "en",
  "background": 
  {
    "scripts": 
    [      
      "js/lib/jserror/jserror.js",
      "js/lib/lang/languagedb.js",

      "js/lib/lz77.js",
      "js/lib/pcrypt.js",
      "js/lib/pcryptapi.js",

      "js/lib/forge.bundle.js",
      "js/lib/elliptic.js",

      "js/lib/srp6a/biginteger.js",
      "js/lib/srp6a/isaac.js",
      "js/lib/srp6a/random.js",
      "js/lib/srp6a/sha256.js",
      "js/lib/srp6a/thinbus-srp6client.js",
      "js/lib/srp6a/thinbus-srp-config.js", 
      "js/lib/srp6a/thinbus-srp6a-config-sha256.js",

      "js/pcrypt_shared.js",      
      "js/pcrypt_extension.js",

      "src/bg/background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "browser_action": 
  {
    "default_icon": 
    {
      "16": "icons/lock_red16.png",
      "48": "icons/lock_red48.png",
      "128": "icons/lock_red128.png"    
    },
    "default_title": "Password Crypt",
    "default_popup": "src/browser_action/popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": 
  [
    "clipboardWrite",
    "storage"
  ],
  "content_scripts": 
  [
    {
      "matches": 
      [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
      ],
      "js": 
      [
        "js/pcrypt_extension.js",

        "src/inject/inject.js"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "externally_connectable":
  {
    "matches": 
    [
        "https://*.aaa.dk/*",
        "https://*.aaa.org/*"
    ]
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": 
  [
    "icons/*.png"
  ],
  "applications": 
  {
    "gecko": 
    {
      "id": "benny@aaa.dk",
      "strict_min_version": "40.0.0",
      "strict_max_version": "50.*",
      "update_url": "https://aaa.org/addon"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As far as I understand it is supposed to be part of the normal page javascript environment and visible in the debugger - but it is not.

No, they're not. They run in slightly more privileged contexts separate from the page environment so they can access the webextension APIs.

If you have e10s off you can use the [browser toolbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Toolbox). If it is on you need to use the browser content toolbox instead. You can also try `about:debugging`, although i'm not sure whether that already works for webextensions.

Comment: All you propose work but no where can I find my content file only the background and popup files!

Comment: assuming you're talking about *inject.js*, i think it will only show if it gets applied to a page after the debugger has been opened

Comment: Found my file in the browser content toolbox

Comment: Looks like it is not running because of this bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1228044. E.g. I use chrome.runtime.sendMessage to begin with from the content script to the background script.

Comment: In firefox 45 (not nightly), I could find my content scripts in the Browser Toolbox. I had to enable Remote Debugging and the Browser Toolbox option in the global settings (see link in answer).

When you're browsing a page where your content script runs, to get the Browser Toolbox, hit the menu button icon (three horizontal bars), then "Developer" (wrench), then "Browser Toolbox".

Also, CTRL-Shift-Alt-i   will open the toolbox.

I find the use of the "debugger;" statement quite useful to avoid digging through the million core scripts and have the toolbox break dynamically.

Comment: @Beast Thank you. This also worked for me, non of my content scripts were showing in the regular browser toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

[MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Debugging) have everything you need to know about debugging WebExt, including content scripts.